# problems related to beamer+\footcite

Tags: beamer, citing

I have three small problems related to beamer+\footcite. I have taken a look on the forum but I have not seen any similar topic.

1) The first one is that I have included a reference inside an overlayarea. I do not know why but it has changed the number (1) to a letter (a) on the footnote.

2)I have cited the same reference on different slides and it appears with anew number each time, I would like that it appears with the same number.

3) I have a reference inside a column. Following a comment read on this forum, I have used the \footnotemark and \footnotetext{\fullcite{reference}} combination. The problem is that there is another reference in the same slide. Both are referenced with the same number.

Here is a brief example with the three problems:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Problem 1}

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.45\textheight}

\end{overlayarea}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.45\textheight}
Here is text \footfullcite{ref01}. 
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Problem 2.1}
Here is text \footfullcite{ref02}.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Problem 2.2}
Here is text \footfullcite{ref02}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Problem 3}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
Third reference\footnotemark.
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\end{columns}
Fourth reference \footfullcite{ref04}.
\footnotetext{\fullcite{ref03}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance,

Ignacio

Comment: Can you please add a small example document that demonstrates your problems?

Answer (score 1):

The `overlayarea` is a `minipage` which has its own symbols for footnotes. This makes sense; the footnote is placed at the bottom of the minipage and not at the bottom of the page. However, if you do not want it, redefinie the minipage environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\makeatletter
\def\@iiiminipage#1#2[#3]#4{%
    \leavevmode
    \@pboxswfalse
    \setlength\@tempdima{#4}%
    \def\@mpargs{{#1}{#2}[#3]{#4}}%
    \setbox\@tempboxa\vbox\bgroup
    \color@begingroup
    \hsize\@tempdima
    \textwidth\hsize \columnwidth\hsize
    \@parboxrestore
    \let\@footnotetext\@mpfootnotetext
    \let\@listdepth\@mplistdepth \@mplistdepth\z@
    \@minipagerestore
    \@setminipage}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Problem 1}

        \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.45\textheight}

        \end{overlayarea}
        \begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{0.45\textheight}
            Here is text \footfullcite{ref01}. 
        \end{overlayarea}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Problem 2.1}
        Here is text \footfullcite{ref02}.\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}{Problem 2.2}
        Here is text \footfullcite{ref02}.
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{Problem 3}
        \begin{columns}
            \column{0.5\textwidth}
            Third reference\footnotemark.
            \column{0.5\textwidth}
        \end{columns}
        \footnotetext{\fullcite{ref03}}
        Fourth reference \footfullcite{ref04}.

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.
Another thing can be done as well. Using the same strategy than with columns, placing the footnotemark in the proper place and the \footnotetext{\fullcite{Boyd_2003}} outside of the overlayarea.